Show $E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D, X\right] = \frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X)}$.
Let $D\in\{0,1\}$ be a binary variable, and $X,A$ be continuous random variables. I want to show $E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D, X\right] = \frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X)}$.
Here is what I have tried using Baye's rule.
First consider $D=1$.
\begin{align*}
E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D=1, X=x\right] &= E_{A\mid D=1, X=x}\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D=1, X=x\right]\\
&= E_{A\mid D=1, X=x}\left[\frac{1}{P(D=1\mid X=x, A)}\mid D=1, X=x\right]\\
&= \int_a \frac{1}{P(D=1\mid X=x, A=a)}\cdot f_{A\mid D=1, X=x}(a\mid D=1, X=x)\,da\\
&=  \int_a \frac{1}{P(D=1\mid X=x, A=a)}\cdot \frac{P(D=1\mid A=a, X=x)f_{A\mid X=x}(a\mid X=x)f_X(x)}{P(D=1\mid X=x) f_X(x)}\,da\\
&=   \frac{1}{P(D=1\mid X=x) }\int_a f_{A\mid X=x}(a\mid X=x) \,da\\
&= \frac{1}{P(D=1\mid X=x) }
\end{align*}
When $D=0$, we have $$E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D=0, X=x\right] = 0.$$
Hence, $$E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D, X\right] =  \frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X=x) }.$$
I tried to be rigorous with the notation. May I ask if there are any mistakes?
More importantly, I would like to gain some insight into this result. It seems that the projection of $\frac{D}{P(D=1 \mid X, A)}$ onto the space $L^2\{\mathcal{P}(D, X)\}$ is similar to what we would obtain by just projecting the denominator $P(D=1 \mid X, A)$ onto $L^2\{\mathcal{P}(X)\}$, while keeping the numerator as what it is.
I understand that, in general, the expectation of a fraction is not equal to the fraction of expectations, so I am cautious about making such observations.

We prove a slightly more general statement. Consider the following setting:

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space
$\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are $\sigma$-algebras such that $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$.
$D : \Omega \to \{0,1\}$ is a binary variable such that $\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G}) > 0$ holds $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely.

Then we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \,\biggm|\, \mathcal{H}, D \biggr] = \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{H})}. \tag{1} $$
OP's case corresponds to the choice $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X, A)$ and $\mathcal{H} = \sigma(X)$.

Proof. In order to prove $\text{(1)}$, let $H \in \mathcal{H}$ and $x \in \{0, 1\}$ be arbitrary. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \mathbf{1}_H \mathbf{1}_{\{D = x\}} \biggr]
&= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{\mathbf{1}_H}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \mathbf{1}_{\{D = 1\}} \biggr] \mathbf{1}_{\{x = 1\}} \\
&= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \mathbb{E} \biggl[ \frac{\mathbf{1}_H}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \mathbf{1}_{\{D = 1\}} \,\biggm|\, \mathcal{G} \biggr] \biggr] \mathbf{1}_{\{x = 1\}} \\
&= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{\mathbf{1}_H}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{D = 1\}} \mid \mathcal{G} ] \biggr] \mathbf{1}_{\{x = 1\}} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbf{1}_H ] \mathbf{1}_{\{x = 1\}}
\end{align*}
Since the above identity holds for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ satisfying $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, it also holds when $\mathcal{G}$ is replaced by $\mathcal{H}$. Hence,
$$ \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \mathbf{1}_H \mathbf{1}_{\{D = x\}} \biggr]
= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{H})} \mathbf{1}_H \mathbf{1}_{\{D = x\}} \biggr] $$
holds. Since $H$ and $x$ are arbitrary, this implies that
$$ \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{G})} \,\biggm|\, \mathcal{H}, D \biggr]
= \mathbb{E}\biggl[ \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{H})} \,\biggm|\, \mathcal{H}, D \biggr]
= \frac{D}{\mathbb{P}(D = 1 \mid \mathcal{H})} $$
as required.

\begin{gather*}
E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid D, X\right]=\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X)}.E\left[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid X\right]=\\
=\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X)}.E\left[E[\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X, A)}\mid X, A]\mid X\right]=\frac{D}{P(D=1\mid X)}
\end{gather*}

Do you mind elaborating on the first equation? I don't see it immediately, perhaps I missed some obvious facts. Thanks!

$E[Y\mid D, X]=E[Y\mid D=1, X]D+EY\mid D=0, X=\frac{E[Y.D\mid X]}{P(D=1\mid X)}D+\frac{E[Y.(1-D)\mid X]}{P(D=0\mid X)}(1-D)$
